# Flutter iOS 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

```
FlutterWebViewController - dealloc
LeakAvoider - dealloc
InAppWebViewMethodHandler - dealloc
WebMessageListener - dealloc
2023-08-02 13:19:24.452817+0900 Runner[29165:2689182] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1cb5a5a24 0x1c4995958 0x1cb733524 0x1cb730358 0x1cb5af974 0x105f9eb4c 0x106348f44 0x1063499f4 0x10624e878 0x1063488a0 0x10634a970 0x106349c40 0x10634a628 0x10624ceb0 0x106250cac 0x1cb660c6c 0x1cb620bfc 0x1cb5c83f0 0x1cb613408 0x1cb617b48 0x201993984 0x1cd9c2638 0x1cd9c22b0 0x10247af64 0x1e83a1df0)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The above error is an error that occurs when I move the page to the iOS app I made on the flutter.
The iOS version is 16.3, the device is the iPhone 8 Plus, and I have never written a separate Swift, Objective C code to cause that error.
It doesn't happen on Android, but only on iOS devices.
Please let me know if you need any additional information